# How to implement multi button click event in Android

Tags: android, button

I have two seperate buttons. I want to do something only when they are BOTH clicked at same time. How can I implement that?

I'm new to Android, and I searched a lot, only finding how to set one listener for multi buttons.

Comment: You can only click one thing at a time... Try searching for multtouch instead

Comment: click means *releasing the view after touching it*. So you basically won't be able to release buttons the same time (up to a millisecond). You likely want to detect simultaneous touch of 2 views

Comment: @zchen were you able to achieve what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a boolean to track click of either button. While that flag is true, if another is clicked too, do your work. Disable the flag after some threshold time. Something like this:

```
  countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(500,100) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            isOneBtnClicked = false;
        }
    };

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isOneBtnClicked) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                isOneBtnClicked = false;
                performSomething(); //whatever you wanted to do
            }
            else {
                isOneBtnClicked = true;
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isOneBtnClicked) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                isOneBtnClicked = false;
                performSomething(); //whatever you wanted to do
            }
            else {
                isOneBtnClicked = true;
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        }
    });
```